# Getters to JSON

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, sequelize.js

I have `sequelize` model `User` with a getter field:

```
public get isExternalUser(): boolean {
  return this.externalLogins.length > 0;
}
```

When I fetch `User` from DB, I can see in debugger that he has `isExternalUser` property set to `false` which is fine, but then when I return it from controller and it gets serialized to JSON, that getter disappers and only `User` fields are serialized.

What am I missing? Are there any settings that can tell `sequelize` that it should serialize getter fields also?

Answer (score 3):

I found a solution. Adding `@Column(DataType.VIRTUAL)` solved the problem:

```
@Column(DataType.VIRTUAL)
get isSalesforceUser(): boolean {
  return this.externalLogins.length > 0;
}
```